# swig/python detected a memory leak of type time_t

Tags: memory-leaks, swig, time-t

My code works, but the following warning appears:

```
swig/python detected a memory leak of type 'time_t *', no destructor found
```

How can I calm it down ?

Comment: Yes, I should define my custom type time_t somehow in SWIG module file. But I do not know more..

Answer (score 2):

Just add `typedef long time_t;` to your SWIG interface file.

Once SWIG knows that `time_t` is a native type, it will not be treated as an object that requires memory management.

Comment: Isn't this a bit dangerous? What if `time_t` is `long long` on some system?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error whenever I accessed a struct member containing a type that wasn't SWIG wrapped.  Not sure if this is your problem (posting your code would help :P), but if so then you could either define your custom time_t in the interface file (just put the C definition in the interface file), or tell SWIG to wrap the (presumably) system header file containing the definition of time_t.